# Xcode + Swift: Is it possible to create custom comment marks?

Tags: swift, xcode, comments, code-organization

In Swift (I'm using Swift 3 / Xcode 8 stable): is it possible to create custom comment mark/tags that can be recognized by Xcode? (and thus added to the jump bar.)

For example, aside from the `// TODO:`, `// FIXME:` or `// MARK:`, can we add new ones, like `// OPTIMIZE:`, `// EVAL:`, or any other custom mark?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, this was done in XCode 10.2.1, just in case anyone rolls past this page. Haven't tested it under XCode 8.

Funny enough was just making a //MARK: comment, and found a new trick. While you can't just to //WHATEVER: to get that showing up the same as //FIXME, etc. What you can do is this.

```
//MARK: WHATEVER: this also works

//MARK: ASDOESTHIS: because why not.
```

Screenshow also attached for proof, hope that helps.

[image: Proof of it working in XCode 11]